# Apache .conf file is not being used

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I have the following `laravel.conf` file for my project:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Where I simply want to redirect all requests to non-www HTTPS. It's however not working as there is no effect if I change anything in there, not even the domain.

I did the following to replace the default `.conf` file:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Is there any other config file that I need to edit? It might be worth mentioning that I am using Let's Encrypt, could it be causing issues?

Comment: Where is `laravel.conf` being included?

Comment: @MrWhite it's listed under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, I have not included it anywhere, `apache2.conf` includes them by default it seems since I see `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` in there.

Comment: is there a link from sites-available to sites-enabled for the config file?

Comment: Running `a2ensite laravel.conf` should create the required symlink (i.e. `.../sites-enabled/laravel.conf` pointing to `.../sites-available/laravel.conf`). Although it's probably still worth double checking it exists...

Answer (score 0):

> it's listed under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, I have not included it anywhere, `apache2.conf` includes them by default it seems since I see `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` in there

"sites-enabled" is not "sites-available"?

But ideally this should also be inside a `<VirtualHost>` container.